# Devise omniauth is redirecting to failure method in callback controller even after successful authentication.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, devise, omniauth

I am working on devise omniauth to authenticate user using facebook. I have implemented it using the documentation https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview
It is not working fine. When I login using my facebook account then it takes me to the "failure" method in the callback controller. 
But the interesting thing is that when I open facebook it open without any problem means it is authenticating my account. 
I have checked it so many times by login and logout from facebook. But the problem is that If it is authenticating facebook account then why it takes me to "failure method".
here is my code

callback controller.

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    render plain: params.inspect
   # redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
  devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
      # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails,
      # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
      # user.skip_confirmation!
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

route code

```
devise_for :users,  controllers: {confirmations: 'confirmations',registrations: 'users/registrations',omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' } do
    #put "confirm_user", to: "confirmations#confirm_user"
    get "confirmation", to: "confirmations#after_confirmation_path_for"
  end
```

Facebook app setting screenshot is

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn8cjpr5wyagkdp/Screenshot%202017-11-27%2017.04.28.png?dl=0

development logs after sign in are

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-11-28 14:13:37 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQA8oLlPsMLSvZf5NqZfOA0oJxDVKczwqqMIxWPD2dJoucpJl9T7MLTmf0mMDlOhgQPAhKa2f6My4vWGZmTWhVo6S5TbSQ3ELup1iBhDHTb869pMMo-ksa1Kh1gJDG65ZJxUj5vAe8jH-DX0eBRpf_ygZACCoFYFTiZdAIzCXQI7jfLaeqH70CqAffkGZczYzhjThM_NLol3Lzo18ZX_6_5n2-p7nMC3IKhmzDEyo_toyaI1telD3QMwa0re7GIu-UXKV4DQp-ClLT452Bigp9Fhs50wYm-Kl08E7195R2mpBESpB7Gu0moDbCgi61dEEk5u8GGfmm0Cxbu9Fcw1_Eu8" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-11-28 14:13:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQA8oLlPsMLSvZf5NqZfOA0oJxDVKczwqqMIxWPD2dJoucpJl9T7MLTmf0mMDlOhgQPAhKa2f6My4vWGZmTWhVo6S5TbSQ3ELup1iBhDHTb869pMMo-ksa1Kh1gJDG65ZJxUj5vAe8jH-DX0eBRpf_ygZACCoFYFTiZdAIzCXQI7jfLaeqH70CqAffkGZczYzhjThM_NLol3Lzo18ZX_6_5n2-p7nMC3IKhmzDEyo_toyaI1telD3QMwa0re7GIu-UXKV4DQp-ClLT452Bigp9Fhs50wYm-Kl08E7195R2mpBESpB7Gu0moDbCgi61dEEk5u8GGfmm0Cxbu9Fcw1_Eu8"}
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 10.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The result of params.inspect is as follows

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"code"=>"AQA8oLlPsMLSvZf5NqZfOA0oJxDVKczwqqMIxWPD2dJoucpJl9T7MLTmf0mMDlOhgQPAhKa2f6My4vWGZmTWhVo6S5TbSQ3ELup1iBhDHTb869pMMo-ksa1Kh1gJDG65ZJxUj5vAe8jH-DX0eBRpf_ygZACCoFYFTiZdAIzCXQI7jfLaeqH70CqAffkGZczYzhjThM_NLol3Lzo18ZX_6_5n2-p7nMC3IKhmzDEyo_toyaI1telD3QMwa0re7GIu-UXKV4DQp-ClLT452Bigp9Fhs50wYm-Kl08E7195R2mpBESpB7Gu0moDbCgi61dEEk5u8GGfmm0Cxbu9Fcw1_Eu8"} permitted: false>
```

The output of rake routes is

```
rake routes
                                Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                                     Controller#Action
                      new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                                        devise/sessions#new
                          user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                                        devise/sessions#create
                  destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                                       devise/sessions#destroy
      user_facebook_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/facebook(.:format)                                  users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
       user_facebook_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/facebook/callback(.:format)                         users/omniauth_callbacks#facebook
       user_twitter_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/twitter(.:format)                                   users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
        user_twitter_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/twitter/callback(.:format)                          users/omniauth_callbacks#twitter
                     new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                                   devise/passwords#new
                    edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)                                  devise/passwords#edit
                         user_password PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                                       devise/passwords#update
                                       PUT      /users/password(.:format)                                       devise/passwords#update
                                       POST     /users/password(.:format)                                       devise/passwords#create
              cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                                         users/registrations#cancel
                 new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                                        users/registrations#new
                edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                                           users/registrations#edit
                     user_registration PATCH    /users(.:format)                                                users/registrations#update
                                       PUT      /users(.:format)                                                users/registrations#update
                                       DELETE   /users(.:format)                                                users/registrations#destroy
                                       POST     /users(.:format)                                                users/registrations#create
                 new_user_confirmation GET      /users/confirmation/new(.:format)                               confirmations#new
                     user_confirmation GET      /users/confirmation(.:format)                                   confirmations#show
                                       POST     /users/confirmation(.:format)                                   confirmations#create
                     new_model_session GET      /models/sign_in(.:format)                                       devise/sessions#new
                         model_session POST     /models/sign_in(.:format)                                       devise/sessions#create
                 destroy_model_session DELETE   /models/sign_out(.:format)                                      devise/sessions#destroy
                    new_model_password GET      /models/password/new(.:format)                                  devise/passwords#new
                   edit_model_password GET      /models/password/edit(.:format)                                 devise/passwords#edit
                        model_password PATCH    /models/password(.:format)                                      devise/passwords#update
                                       PUT      /models/password(.:format)                                      devise/passwords#update
                                       POST     /models/password(.:format)                                      devise/passwords#create
             cancel_model_registration GET      /models/cancel(.:format)                                        devise/registrations#cancel
                new_model_registration GET      /models/sign_up(.:format)                                       devise/registrations#new
               edit_model_registration GET      /models/edit(.:format)                                          devise/registrations#edit
                    model_registration PATCH    /models(.:format)                                               devise/registrations#update
                                       PUT      /models(.:format)                                               devise/registrations#update
                                       DELETE   /models(.:format)                                               devise/registrations#destroy
                                       POST     /models(.:format)                                               devise/registrations#create
                new_model_confirmation GET      /models/confirmation/new(.:format)                              devise/confirmations#new
                    model_confirmation GET      /models/confirmation(.:format)                                  devise/confirmations#show
                                       POST     /models/confirmation(.:format)                                  devise/confirmations#create
               donations_donor_history GET      /donations/donor_history(.:format)                              donations#donor_history
                donations_donor_signup GET      /donations/donor_signup(.:format)                               donations#donor_signup
                                       POST     /donations/donor_signup(.:format)                               donations#donor_signup
                 donations_sms_service POST     /donations/sms_service(.:format)                                donations#sms_service
         donations_create_user_account POST     /donations/create_user_account(.:format)                        donations#create_user_account
            donations_add_user_payroll POST     /donations/add_user_payroll(.:format)                           donations#add_user_payroll
                             donations GET      /donations(.:format)                                            donations#index
                         edit_donation GET      /donations/:id/edit(.:format)                                   donations#edit
                              donation GET      /donations/:id(.:format)                                        donations#show
                                       PATCH    /donations/:id(.:format)                                        donations#update
                                       PUT      /donations/:id(.:format)                                        donations#update
                                       DELETE   /donations/:id(.:format)                                        donations#destroy
                    campaign_donations POST     /campaigns/:campaign_id/donations(.:format)                     donations#create
                 new_campaign_donation GET      /campaigns/:campaign_id/donations/new(.:format)                 donations#new
campaign_donations_create_user_account GET      /campaigns/:campaign_id/donations/create_user_account(.:format) donations#create_user_account
                             campaigns GET      /campaigns(.:format)                                            campaigns#index
                                       POST     /campaigns(.:format)                                            campaigns#create
                          new_campaign GET      /campaigns/new(.:format)                                        campaigns#new
                         edit_campaign GET      /campaigns/:id/edit(.:format)                                   campaigns#edit
                              campaign GET      /campaigns/:id(.:format)                                        campaigns#show
                                       PATCH    /campaigns/:id(.:format)                                        campaigns#update
                                       PUT      /campaigns/:id(.:format)                                        campaigns#update
                                       DELETE   /campaigns/:id(.:format)                                        campaigns#destroy
                         organizations GET      /organizations(.:format)                                        organizations#index
                                       POST     /organizations(.:format)                                        organizations#create
                      new_organization GET      /organizations/new(.:format)                                    organizations#new
                     edit_organization GET      /organizations/:id/edit(.:format)                               organizations#edit
                          organization GET      /organizations/:id(.:format)                                    organizations#show
                                       PATCH    /organizations/:id(.:format)                                    organizations#update
                                       PUT      /organizations/:id(.:format)                                    organizations#update
                                       DELETE   /organizations/:id(.:format)                                    organizations#destroy
          admins_social_sharing_switch POST     /admins/social_sharing_switch(.:format)                         admins#social_sharing_switch
                   admins_error_detail GET      /admins/error_detail(.:format)                                  admins#error_detail
                                       GET      /admins/generate_report/:id(.:format)                           admins#generate_report
                 admins_create_company GET      /admins/create_company(.:format)                                admins#create_company
                                       POST     /admins/create_company(.:format)                                admins#create_company
                 admins_revenue_detail GET      /admins/revenue_detail(.:format)                                admins#revenue_detail
                 admins_create_account GET      /admins/create_account(.:format)                                admins#create_account
                   admins_view_account GET      /admins/view_account(.:format)                                  admins#view_account
                                       GET      /admins/view_company/:id(.:format)                              admins#view_company
              admins_donation_analysis GET      /admins/donation_analysis(.:format)                             admins#donation_analysis
                    admins_link_expiry GET      /admins/link_expiry(.:format)                                   admins#link_expiry
                   admins_edit_profile GET      /admins/edit_profile(.:format)                                  admins#edit_profile
                 admins_update_profile POST     /admins/update_profile(.:format)                                admins#update_profile
                                       POST     /admins/create_account(.:format)                                admins#create_account
                         admin_destroy GET      /admins/:id(.:format)                                           admins#destroy
                                admins GET      /admins(.:format)                                               admins#index
                                       POST     /admins(.:format)                                               admins#create
                             new_admin GET      /admins/new(.:format)                                           admins#new
                            edit_admin GET      /admins/:id/edit(.:format)                                      admins#edit
                                 admin GET      /admins/:id(.:format)                                           admins#show
                                       PATCH    /admins/:id(.:format)                                           admins#update
                                       PUT      /admins/:id(.:format)                                           admins#update
                                       DELETE   /admins/:id(.:format)                                           admins#destroy
                crons_expirylink_alert GET      /crons/expirylink_alert(.:format)                               crons#expirylink_alert
                        users_sign_out GET      /users/sign_out(.:format)                                       devise/sessions#destroy
                                  root GET      /                                                               campaigns#latest
```

Comment: have you create app on facebook developer account and add keys?

Comment: @puneet18 yes I have setup everything.

Comment: can you paste screenshot of facebook app setting

Comment: also have you created file app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb?

Comment: @puneet18 I have attached.

Comment: @puneet18 please see the code i have clearly mentioned the controller.

Comment: You have to make your app live and add live url in facebook app then it will work

Comment: Install ngrok on your machine using which you can make your app live and add ngrok url to fb app for testing

Comment: Can you copy & paste the server log from `log/development.log`?

Comment: @Mirv have a look at the edited question. I have add the logs.

Comment: I'm at work - so you might go 12 hours without a reply from me!  If it's urgent & worth it - I suggest you hit upwork.com or such ... there's smaller bid style sites too.  My only comment right now is I see you have a `params.inspect` & you don't show us the results of it?  Also, are you redirecting back to current page already?  It might be as simple as following the guide here - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: @Mirv the result of params are included.Please have a look at edited question.

Comment: What about the other question I included?

Comment: @Mirv no I am not redirecting it to current page. It should go to the "facebook" method in the callback controller but it is going to the "failure" method.

Comment: When you copy & pasted that `param.inspect`, did you notice anything weird in there?  Are you permitting that parameter in your controller per `strong_params` as instructed in rails guide? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: It is not a redirect problem. After the facebook authentication It should go to the "facebook" callback method in the controller. This is the default behaviour. I think you will understand now. In this official guide/tutorial https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview it is not mention anything about permitting any params.Which params should I permit?

Comment: All I understand is you say it's not directing correctly & then you just told me it's not a redirect issue.  If the not permitted error in your code isn't fixing it you, need to start simplifying your code to trace the issue with flags or use pry to figure out why it's not reaching the facebook page you desire.

Comment: @Mirv Ok keep it simple. After authenticating facebook the program control is going in "failure" method not in the "facebook" method. Now please help me. Is it ok now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160007/discussion-between-john-and-mirv).

Comment: I don't know the answer since I can't poke around your server, I suggested you look into the `param.inspect`, then you should notice `permitted: false` is there ... after that follow the link I already provided for an explanation of `strong_params`.  Once you figure that out - you will probably fix your issue.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Where have you configured to redirect the request to `failure` action in case authentication fails?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have paste the routes.Please have a look.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have not configured authentication failure route anywhere. After login credentials entry it directly goes to failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hardwork of 2 days I have finally solved it myself. Every thing was fine except the gem itself. If you just write the `gem omniauth-facebook` it would install version 1.4.0 which is very old. I update it to gem `'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0'` and it is working like a charm. So if anyone face the same issue he should update the gem.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Yeah. You can upvote the answer if you think this question can be useful for others.Thanks.